# Pythonic way to iterate a dictionary to convert its items to string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, printing

I have a dictionary such as:

```
a = { "Linux": "Linus Torvalds", 
      "Microsoft": "Bill Gates", 
      "Apple": "Steve Jobs"}
```

I want to stringify this dictionary to something like this:

```
Linux    : Linus Torvalds
Microsoft: Bill Gates
Apple    : Steve Jobs
```

For doing this operation, I have the following code:

```
data = ""
for product, lead in a.items():
    data += product + ": " + lead + "\n"
```

This code produces the following result:

```
print(data)
Linux: Linus Torvalds
Microsoft: Bill Gates
Apple: Steve Jobs
```

I would like a more Pythonic way to perform this operation as I think my code is more of a procedural method for solving this problem (initializing and manipulating). Also, any tips on properly formatting the `data` won't be amiss.

Comment: Why would you want to make strings here, for visualization? I can't imagine a case where this is a good idea

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes. I want to print the data.

Comment: Just iterate then, `for k,v in a.items(): print(k,v)` or you could use `pprint` but it's probably overkill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get them formatted like you have

```
print('\n'.join(['{:<9}: {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in a.items()]))
```

prints

```
Apple    : Steve Jobs
Linux    : Linus Torvalds
Microsoft: Bill Gates
```

Comment: you could also use the starred format like: `.format(*pair) for pair in a.items()`. I like this approach a bit better for the control over the line format it allows.

Comment: Thanks for your solution and @Kounis for the suggestion.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis explicit is better than implicit. It helps to document which is which in this case.

Comment: @MarkRansom Then the OP's original solution was also fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a nested [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) operation.

```
print('\n'.join(': '.join(item) for item in a.items()))
#  Linux: Linus Torvalds
#  Microsoft: Bill Gates
#  Apple: Steve Jobs
```

This creates a generator that contains the keys and values separated by `': '` and then join them together with '`\n`'.

Comment: Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 1):

First convert the `dict` to an iterable with `map` and then join the elements using `join`:

```
work_person = map(lambda x: x[0]+': '+x[1], a.items())    
res = '\n'.join(work_person)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add to Patrick's answer checking the longest key length to pad the keys:

```
max_length = max(len(k) for k in a)
print('\n'.join(['{:<{}}: {}'.format(k, max_length, v) for k, v in a.items()]))
```